# Взять первые цифры из String и засетать их как Int Java

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне достать перых 6 цифр из этой стори, если она String/

И  после мне нужно их засетать вот сюда
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот еще фрагмент когда где это используеться
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать метод substring(start,end), который возвращает подстроку, а дальше Integer.parseInt использовать чтоб преобразовать в число.
Вот пример...

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = "00001121021 01 07...";
        Integer number = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0,6));

        System.out.println(number); \\ 11
    }
}
```